# How to bind a binary property to a property with multiple values?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ToggleButton being a standard WPF class and I want to bind IsChecked to a property status of my model and the Status can have more than 2 values: Status1, Status2, Status3, Status4. The type of `Status`  is `SomeThirdPartyClassStatus` and I don't have access to its source code.

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Status???}" />
```

So how can I bind Status to `IsChecked` then? I prefer a xaml solution.

I want to bind `IsChecked` property so that it's True when the Status is equal to Status1, and it's false in other cases. I prefer not to write any code in a *.cs file, but only xaml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can use pure XAML solution with `DataTrigger`. Assuming that you have something like

```
public enum SomeThirdPartyClassStatus {
    Status1, 
    Status2, 
    Status3, 
    Status4
}
```

you can do

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static local:SomeThirdPartyClassStatus.Status1}">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Where `local` is namespace for `SomeThirdPartyClassStatus` like

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

Caveat is that it will work **one-way only**

**EDIT**

For two-way binding you'll need custom `IValueConverter`

```
public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (SomeThirdPartyClassStatus)value == SomeThirdPartyClassStatus.Status1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool?)value == true ? SomeThirdPartyClassStatus.Status1 : SomeThirdPartyClassStatus.Status2;
    }
}
```

and then the binding would look like

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: I need 2 ways. is there any way to make it work 2-ways?

Comment: Hi @OskarK., what happened to your "no code behind" request xD !

Comment: @SamTheDev, nothing.

Comment: In case of MVVM approach you can have a `boolean` property in your view model which relates to your `enum` property in model.

Comment: Have I said the mentioned solutions cannot be used for MVVM?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class derived from IValueConverter which you apply to your binding.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Simply use this style for toggle button

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Status1" >
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
         </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>        
</Style>
```

So if ever Status has value Status1 toggle button will be checked.

Comment: I added it to Window.Resources -> ResourceDictionary, but it doesn't work. Should I do anything else?

Comment: firstly you should check this by defining on the local page resources to check the output. but in your case have you merged the dictionaries in local page?